# How to iterate through all values of an array?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to implement a brute-force algorithm.

If I have one variable `x`, I can iterate through all its values using a `for` loop:

```
for x in {1,2,..,MAX}:
    do something with x
```

But what if I have an array `A`?  The array has length `SIZE`, and each element takes values in the range `1..MAX`.  Thus, there are `MAX^SIZE` possible values of this array.  How do I iterate through all such possible values?

I'm asking for an algorithm, not an implementation on a particular language. Both `MAX` and `SIZE` are arguments.  `SIZE` is not fixed, so I can't just create a set of nested for-loops (the number of for-loops that would be needed isn't fixed in advance and depends on the value of `SIZE`).

Comment: This is such a low-level algorithm that, to me, it's just a programming question. Hint: treat the array as a SIZE-digit number written in base-MAX.

Comment: [Meta question about the closure of this question](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/what-is-question-about-low-level-algorithm) Cc @DavidRicherby

Comment: Thanks for concentrating on one question and explicitly stating the availability of _MAX_ and _SIZE_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several approaches.  I will use 0-based indexing (so array elements are in the range `0 .. MAX-1`) rather than 1-based indexing (range `1 .. MAX`), for ease of notation.

### Treat as an integer

You can treat the contents of an array as an integer in the range `0 .. MAX^SIZE - 1`, expressed in base `MAX`.  For example, the array with contents `[0, 3, 1]` corresponds to the integer `0 * MAX^2 + 3 * MAX + 1`.  Conversely, each such integer corresponds to an array.

Of course you can iterate through these integers by starting at 0 and incrementing until you reach `MAX^SIZE - 1`.  Now by expressing that integer in base `MAX`, you can convert the integer to an array, and thereby iterate through all possible values of the array.

### Depth-first search

You can view this as a complete tree of depth `SIZE`, where each internal node has branching factor `MAX`.  Each leaf of the tree corresponds to a value of the array.  Then, you can iterate through the leaves of the tree following any standard [tree traversal algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

### Direct iteration

To iterate through these arrays, it suffices to create an order on the arrays and build an algorithm to advance from one array to the next-largest array.  For this, you can use lexicographic order.  The smallest (first) such array is the all-zeros array `[0, 0, ..., 0]`.

Given an array `A`, you can advance to the next array in lexicographic order via a simple procedure.  Basically, you increment the last element of the array; if that becomes too large (equal to `MAX`), it wraps around to 0, and then you increment the next-to-last element of the array (continuing if it wraps around).  If you think about it a bit, this is basically equivalent to the "treat as an integer" solution.

### Running time

All of these methods have basically the same running time.  Asymptotically they all require approximately `MAX^SIZE` operations.  Depending on representation and implementation details, direct iteration might be slightly faster, but the differences are likely to be minor.

(The fine print: depending upon implementation details, the running time of the "treat as an integer" method might be more like `SIZE * MAX^SIZE`.)

There's no algorithm that can iterate through all values of the array in less than `MAX^SIZE` operations (as the number of possible arrays is a lower bound on the time to iterate through them all), so there's no hope for an algorithm that is significantly better.

Comment: The "direct iteration" is exactly what I was looking for. All I need to do is to implement a method next() that increases the array in that lexicographic order, then loop until the array doesn't "hasNext". When I asked, the problem appeared too difficult for me, but after you answered, it looks trivial now :) Thank you.

Comment: "Treat as an integer" is a clever hack, but converting to integer is not practical with large values of SIZE and RANGE.